# UITableVIew Fails To render UITableViewCell Currectly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I am going to populate my tableView with different states one state act wrong, I'm sure that it cause by delay of tableView. please see video and picture first.

I populating my UITableView like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
              cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId")
    cell.state = myStates[indexPath.row]
}
```

on my `UITableViewCell`:

```
var state: MyCustomDesignState? {
    didSet {
        self.button.set(state: self.state)
    }
}
```

on my `UIButton`:

```
func set(state: MyCustomDesignState?) {
    switch state { 
    case ...
    case .blackBack:
        self.backgroundColor = background
        self.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
        self.frame = CGRect.init(x: 40, y: 190 - 40, width: 180, height: 34)
        self.dropFlatShadow(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.1008123383, green: 0.1008369699, blue: 0.1008091196, alpha: 1))
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }
}
```

this is what I want, and what I did get:

[image]

how my tableView looks like:

video to bug:

https://streamable.com/ki7vx

Comment: It looks like you are mixing explicit frame setting: *'self.frame = CGRect.init(x: 40, y: 190 - 40, width: 180, height: 34)'* with auto-layout. Is the button is in a stack view?

Comment: no @DonMag it is have auto layout with storyboard in leading and trailing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TableViewCell` : Try calling this method which you are currently calling in state change like below :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
          super.layoutSubviews()
          self.button.set(state: self.state)
    }
```

Hope I got the question right and this helps you.

Comment: Add a call to `super.layoutSubviews()` within that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have designed your cell in Storyboard, using leading and trailing constraints, those constraints will be "re-laid-out" by auto-layout.

So, using this line:

```
self.frame = CGRect.init(x: 40, y: 190 - 40, width: 180, height: 34)
```

will only affect the frame until the next auto-layout pass -- such as when you scroll the tableView.

You probably only want to give the button a Leading constraint. If you want it wider than the text - that is, padding on the left and right - give your button `Content Inset` values.

Comment: i tried to use IBOutlet leading and trailing constraint connect to UIButton class but i dont know why my crashes. every time leading or trailing NSLayoutConstraint will be null like when i forget to connect.